# auto type deduction for function g++ 6.2

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

I am experimenting with modern C++ 'auto' and found a simple example that produces an error and I can't understand why:

**main.cpp**

```
// error: use of ‘auto test(int)’ before deduction of ‘auto’ int i = test(5);
int i = test(5);
```

**test.h**

```
auto test(int i);
```

**test.cpp**

```
auto test(int i) {
  if (i == 1)
    return i;               // return type deduced as int
  else
    return Correct(i-1)+i;  // ok to call it now
}
```

But if I specify the type using '->' the code builds and runs fine.  For example:

```
auto test(int i) -> int;
```

g++ 6.2 is a modern version of the compiler and I would like to know why I must use '-> int'.  Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return type deduction simply can't work for declarations. The compiler uses the definition (implementation) to deduce the type by checking what the function actually returns. In a declaration it's not possible to do that, and so the compilation will fail when you call the function because there's no deduced return type yet.

When you use the trailing return type you explicitly specify the return type. In your case it's no different than using the old "normal" way of declaring return type.

Comment: What confused me was this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Function_return_type_deduction

Comment: I understand what you said about not being able to deduce a return type from a declaration, but can you give me some hints why there are samples on the web like the ones found in the Wikipedia link I sent above?  I'd pretty much like to know why they write those examples if they won't compile.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran From the Wikipedia link you provide: "Functions that deduce their return types can be forward declared, but they cannot be used until they have been defined. Their definitions must be available to the translation unit that uses them." So the declaration can be used for forward declarations, provided that the definition is before you call the function.